# Change url of file_get_contents based on time

Tags: php, datetime, file-get-contents

$string = file_get_contents("http://domain.com/api/data?after=1412640000");

My PHP code displays the json data based on the epoch time. This time is always at 00:00:00 UTC. I need the time in the url to change at different time frames like 1 day when it is available.

I can put a variable in the url to get the current time but Im lost on the setting it to 00:00:00 UTC for when the new day would roll over.

Ive searched and I keeping getting partial results but not quite what I need. First time posting here. Thanks for the help.

Edit: I got this to work for daily changes but I need two other time frames like one week and a month.

Heres the code:

```
$daily = gmdate(strtotime('yesterday'));
$string = file_get_contents("http://domain.com/api/data?after={$daily}");
```

The gmdate is what did the trick for UTC. Now for a week time frame. An example would be displaying the date of the 2nd of the month until the week rolls over then it displays the new weekly date from the 9th.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so finally figured it out. Here is the code to enter epoch from certain date time intervals of daily, weekly and monthly all in UTC.

```
$daily = gmdate(strtotime('yesterday'));
$string = file_get_contents("http://domain.com/api/data?after={$daily}");

$weekly = mktime(23, 59, 59, date('n'), date('j'), date('Y')) - ((date('N'))*3600*24);
$string = file_get_contents("http://domain.com/api/data?after={$weekly}");

$monthly = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1, date('Y'));
$string = file_get_contents("http://domain.com/api/data?after={$monthly}");
```

$daily is the simplest and easiest. $weekly will start with Mondays and will give that time until the next Monday comes around and thats also how $monthly works but with on the 1st.

Answer (score 0):

strtotime is more powerful than you think, just the naive way works:

```
strtotime("-1 week")
strtotime("-1 month")
```

Comment: Ah yes but then "-1 week" always returns one week ago from any time instead of displaying a week for a week then changing to the new weekly date. Does that make sense?

Comment: if you need a pagination like query you can just iterate -1 week, -2 week, etc. Does that answer your question?

Comment: No. The page would display the data from the weekly date for one week. After seven days it changes to the new week date and displays that data for a week. Same goes for a monthly time frame.

Comment: Ok Ive been playing with mktime. I get the results I want but am not sure if its the most efficient or fastest way. Strtotime seems so much cleaner. so this is what I use for weekly and monthly. Maybe there is a better way?


    $weekly = mktime(23, 59, 59, date('n'), date('j'), date('Y')) - ((date('N'))*3600*24); 


    $monthly =  mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1, date('Y'));